# How to get m2repo directory in java?

Tags: java, maven, directory, repository

To make my code flexible I would like to find a way to get the maven 2 repository directory via a function like `System.getProperty("m2repo")` or something, as we do for the classpath `System.getProperty("java.class.path")`.

Is this possible?

Comment: Maybe we should first elaborate, why you need access to the Maven repository. Are you writing a maven plugin?

Comment: Yes, I am writing a maven plugin.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can inject this value into your Mojo like this:

```
/**
* @parameter expression="${settings.localRepository}"
*/
private String localRepository;
```